# Elastic search 2.x issues

Tags: elasticsearch

What are the major issues Elastic search 2.4 has as it directly has 
moved to 5.x? There is no version in between 2.4 and 5.x? 
Will everything will be changed while upgrading from 2.4 to 5.x

Comment: You can find the story of the version jump in Shay Banon's blog post at https://www.elastic.co/blog/heya-elastic-stack-and-x-pack (hint: it was mainly to streamline the version numbers between all their products and have a consistent versioning from 5.0 onwards)

Comment: To find what the (breaking) changes are between versions 2.x and 5.0, check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/breaking-changes-5.0.html